# XHR JSON response starts with for

Tags: ajax, json, cross-domain

I was looking at some facebook XHR request. I seen that there is a request that is cross domain, and the response is a JSON like:

```
for (;;); {/* JSON object */}
```

Why that response starts with a *for*???
I think it is related to some security reason, can someone explain me it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done to protect against XSS.

If a malicious site includes that JSON URL in a `<script>` tag, the browser will freeze.
The actual client site can just strip the prefix; other sites cannot, because of the Same-Origin Policy.

Comment: ok, so, using CORS you can call this JSON using a normal XHR request, but if you try to include it in a page using the script tag the browser will freeze. Is it correct?

Comment: Correct, except that CORS has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Why not? The request is from _http://facebook.com_ to _http://0-staging.channel.facebook.com_ and use the header specified in the CORS document of the W3C (the Access-Control-Allow-Origin). Sorry, but I'm studying this stuff right now, and I'm curious about all the problems of the Cross Domain...

Comment: I see.  CORS has nothing to do with the technique itself.